# How do I do a sinon stub to replace the promise so that the response is mocked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want the whole promise stubbed.

I'm using angular js version 1 with javascript and jasemine and karma.

**Here is my code:**

```
appcontrolmod.controller('loginCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'personService', 
    function ($rootScope, $scope personService) {   

    $scope.getUser= function(){

        //I want to stub this to return an expected response?
        personService.getUser().then((response) => {

                //I want to stub the response of this promise?
                console.log(response);

                if(response){
                    //update model
                }else{
                    //show error message
                }

        });

    }

    $scope.getUser();
}]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do put `$httpBackend.get` on url of `personService.getUser()` method

Comment: There is no http call

Comment: I just need to mock this promise with a stub

Comment: then what `personService.getUser()` does?

Comment: Doesn't matter because I'm not interested in testing the next layer. Just need to mock the response of the promise with a stub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that place spy over the method and just return some fake data from that spy

```
//place spy over it & return fakedata, it should be in global before each
var getUserSpy = spyOn(personService, 'getUser').and.callFake(function() {
  return {
    then: function(callback) { return callback({Id: 1, Name: 'Something'}); }
  };
});

it('should show success when modal login returns success response', function() {
    scope.getUser();
    //do assert by calling expect statement
    expect(personService.getUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(scope.user.Id).toBe(1); //assuming scope.user has filled with response user data
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that, but I was really wanting a stub way of doing it with Sinon

Comment: @AngularM you should try this out..should work. Thanks :)

Comment: I know but it needs to be a Sinon stub

Comment: @AngularM can you just brief about ` Sinon stub`? honestly I don't know that term,,

Comment: Sinon stub is part of sinonjs and it creates a test double for the code so that it reacts how you want

Comment: Pankja in your above example how do i test the response without mapping it to the scope e.g. so there would be no scope.user.id

Comment: @AngularM you have to have scope inside your test case, as you are testing out controller scope,, I don't understand why you don't want it..

Comment: the code above doesnt work because the spy on wont work for a promise